# Why did Anastasia make that choice in the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, fifty-shades-of-grey

In [*Fifty Shades of Grey* (2015)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt00002322441/), I didn't understand why Anastasia left Grey in the end. She is asking him to show her how bad he wants to "punish" her, so he shows her. After that she is crying and says "don't touch me" and then leaves. At first Grey said it would be carnal pleasures (Dom-Sub). Why does she leave? Is it because she was hurt or some other reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My interpretation is pretty simple. At the end, Anastasia is no longer consenting, and the scene becomes more of a rape than anything else. Katherine O'Clare, of Crushable, wrote:

> Christian Grey is an abuser. He is emotionally unavailable, emotionally abusive, and sexually exploitative. His complete disregard for his partner’s comfort, experience, and emotional well being are contemptible: he gets his pleasure at the expense of his partner ...
>   All sexual relationships, whether vanilla or kinky, require consent. There is no such thing as having sex that is not based in consent. The only thing that happens without it is rape.

That is what happens in the last scene. This movie really isn't about BDSM, which require trust and respect, and not an informal business contract. These tears clearly show she does not want to be there anymore, and the fact she leaves shows that beyond her love for him, she knows she has been a victim.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the movie, but in the book, "Fifty Shades of Grey", she leaves because she finally realizes how "incompatible" she is with him.

Answer (score 0):

Guess she is tired of getting **Naked** for responsive reproach.

> Anastasia: What if i say i feel the same way you feel, when i touch you
>
> Christian Grey: I have to punish you!!, that is how i am.

that's a straight up turn off for any lady "*i know you know that*"

*the dialog is not exact but it is 70% close, in the ending moments of the movie*